# condition in loop in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, normal-distribution

I have a relative simple question for which I was not able to apply solutions I have found on the internet. Let's say we have:

```
set.seed(20)

data <- data.frame(month = rep(month.name, 25), 
a = rnorm(300, 0, 1), b = runif(300, 0, 7.2))
```

I want to calculate using a loop the f-test for variance between columns **a** and **b** for each month in **month**. This I done by using:

```
# create some empty vectors to fill in later
pval <- as.double()
ftest <- as.double()
month <- as.character()

# looping through the months

for (i in unique(data$month)){
  print(i)
  # sh.1 <- shapiro.test(data$a[data$month==i])
  # sh.1[2] > 0.05 # apply log if it's smaller than 0.05
  # sh.2 <- shapiro.test(data$b[data$month==i])
  # sh.2[2] > 0.05 # apply log if it's smaller than 0.05
  var.t <- var.test(data$a[data$month==i], data$b[data$month==i])
  f <- round(var.t[[1]],2)
  p <- round(var.t$p.value,2)
  ftest <- append(ftest, f)
  pval <- append(pval, p)
  month <- append(month, i)
}
```

However, as far as I know, f-test is very sensitive to normal distribution. Therefore, I am planning to use a condition into loop where in case that p-value of shapiro test is smaller than 0.05 a *log* transformation for the data will be required; then it will be used into f-test.

Normally, I would to this with an ifelse condition but I am not very sure how to use it here.
Any help here please?

Comment: Are you sure that the data is positive? logs can only be computed for positive values and your column `a` is drawn from a normal.

Comment: Yes, data is positive. I created also a column with normalized values in order to make example more representative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the code below does what you want. It uses `*apply` loops, not `for` loops in order to make the code more readable (I think).

First I will recreate the data and make sure column `a` is all positive.

```
set.seed(20)

data <- data.frame(month = rep(month.name, 25), 
                   a = rnorm(300, 0, 1), b = runif(300, 0, 7.2))

data$a <- abs(data$a)
```

Now, instead of looping through unique values of `month`, I split the data.frame by that variable. Like this each of the df's in the resulting list `sp` already is a df of all rows of each month.

```
sp <- split(data, data$month)
sp <- sp[order(order(month.name))]
```

It's here that the data are `log` transformed if necessary.

```
sp <- lapply(sp, function(DF){
  if(shapiro.test(DF[["a"]])$p.value < 0.05) DF[["a"]] <- log(DF[["a"]])
  if(shapiro.test(DF[["b"]])$p.value < 0.05) DF[["b"]] <- log(DF[["b"]])
  DF
})
```

And `lapply` the test you want, `var.test`, to all of these data.frames.

```
vartest_list <- lapply(sp, function(DF){
  var.t <- var.test(DF[["a"]], DF[["b"]])
  list(f = var.t[[1]], 
       p.value = var.t$p.value, 
       month = as.character(DF[["month"]][1]))
})
```

Finally, it is a simple matter of applying the extraction function `[[` to the tests' results. This works because hypothesis tests functions in R return objects of class `"htest"` that are nothing else but lists. The last of the extraction loops is commented out.

```
ftest <- sapply(vartest_list, '[[', 'f')
pval <- sapply(vartest_list, '[[', 'p.value')
#month <- sapply(vartest_list, '[[', 'month')
```

Comment: thank you for your time. I am not very familiar with sapply or lapply. In case of sapply, for example "[[" is for what? I know is related to lists but I am not sure why the squared brackets doesn't need to be closed as well.

Comment: @AndreiNiță `'[['` is a function, an extraction function. See `?Extract` and note that that's the same help page as `?'[['`. The `sapply` calls in my answer apply the function `[[` to each member of the list `vartest_list` passing the argument `'f'` or `'p.value'`. Those are the sub-list members to extract. (Each `vartest_list` member is a list of class `"htest"` so use list extraction functions to get their members.)

Comment: @AndreiNiță Try the following: `tmp <- vartest_list[[1]]`. Now `tmp` is the result of the first test. Then `tmp[['p.value']]`. The second `sapply` does this in a compact way looping through all `vartest_list` members. Another way to see it, without `tmp`, would be `vartest_list[[1]][['p.value']]` then `vartest_list[[2]][['p.value']]`, then etc.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you again for your time and for your extensive answer. I enriched my knowledges in R today a bit :)